# How to scale individual image within a forEach loop?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a ListView that has 20 items and uses the following Image within the `ForEach` loop:

```
Image(systemName: "heart").foregroundColor(.red).onTapGesture {
        selected.toggle()
        favLists.append(country.id)
        favLists = favLists.removingDuplicates()
    }
.scaleEffect(self.selected ? 1.5 : 1)
```

The issue is that `selected` is a single variable, so that is toggling the state for ALL my items in the list.  How can I declare dynamic state dependent on the number of index items?

Comment: Perhaps store a `selectedItemID` instead of just a `Bool` for `selected`

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that represents your situation, including the `ForEach`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the Swift language function `forEach()` is different than the SwiftUI function `ForEach()`. You should edit your question title and correct the casing to read `ForEach`, since it seems you’re asking about the SwiftUI function.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach, `...to scale individual image within a ForEach loop`, works for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selected = "heart"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            ForEach(["globe", "house", "person", "heart"], id: \.self) { name in
                Image(systemName: name).id(name)
                    .onTapGesture { 
                       selected = name 
                       // ....other code
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(selected == name ? .red : .blue)
                    .scaleEffect(selected == name ? 2.5 : 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```